# Using .SDcols and .SD with two groups of columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to use .SD / .SDcols with two groups of columns?

I.e. in the code below, in the last line I need to multiple columns of the first group (colA) by the corresponding columns of the second group (colsA), as shown:

```
colA <- paste0("a", 1:3);     colB <- paste0("b", 1:3)
colC <- paste0("c", 1:3)

dt <- data.table(V1=1:3);dt                   # just creating a data.table to work with 
dt[, (colA):=.(1:3,4:6,7:9)][, V1:=NULL][]
dt[, (colB):=.(11:13,14:16,17:19)][]

dt[, (colC):= .SD * .SD, .SDcols=colA][]      # is done efficiently using `data.table`
dt[ , (colC):= .SD1 * .SD2, .SDcols1=colA, .SDcols2=colB][] # Is that possible using `data.table` framework?
```

It often happens, when you have hundreds of columns with some values  and then another hundred of columns with some normalizing values, which you need to multiply (or divide) to another. Currently, I just simply use `for` loop to do that, which negates all the power and beauty  of `data.table`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited 2021-06-14 to cover the `env` parameter available with development version 1.14.1 of `data.table`.**

The [release notes for data.table v1.11.0 (01 May 2018)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1110--01-may-2018) state:

> Thus, `with=` should no longer be needed in any cases. Please change to
> using the `..` prefix and over the next few years we will start to
> formally deprecate and remove the `with=` parameter.

So, here are three other options:

#### Using the `..` prefix

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.12.9 used
dt[, (colC) := .SD[, ..colA] * .SD[, ..colB]][]
```

> ```
>    a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2  c3
> 1:  1  4  7 11 14 17 11 56 119
> 2:  2  5  8 12 15 18 24 75 144
> 3:  3  6  9 13 16 19 39 96 171
> ```

Although the result is as expected, there are warning messages

> 1: In [.data.table(.SD, , ..colA) :   Both 'colA'
> and '..colA' exist in calling scope. Please remove the '..colA'
> variable in calling scope for clarity.
> 2: In [.data.table(.SD, ,
> ..colB) :   Both 'colB' and '..colB' exist in calling scope. Please
> remove the '..colB' variable in calling scope for clarity.

To get rid of the warnings, an intermediate result can be used

```
tmp <- dt[, ..colA] * dt[, ..colB]
dt[, (colC) := tmp][]
```

#### Using `mget()`

`mget()` works for me as well:

```
dt[, (colC) := .SD[, mget(colA)] * .SD[, mget(colB)]][]
```

#### EDIT: Using the new `env` argument

With development version 1.14.1 as of 2021-05-10, a new interface for *programming on data.table* has been added (see [item 10 in NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features),  the new vignette *programming on data.table*, and [jangorecki's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354689/using-sdcols-and-sd-with-two-groups-of-columns-in-data-table/62373195#comment110287235_62354896) on https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304).

The recommend way is to use the new `env` argument:

```
dt[, (colC) := .SD[, x] * .SD[, y], env = I(list(x = colA, y = colB))][]
```

> ```
>    a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2  c3
> 1:  1  4  7 11 14 17 11 56 119
> 2:  2  5  8 12 15 18 24 75 144
> 3:  3  6  9 13 16 19 39 96 171
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
colA <- paste0("a", 1:3)
colB <- paste0("b", 1:3)
colC <- paste0("c", 1:3)
dt <- data.table(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 11:13, 14:16, 17:19)
setnames(dt, c(colA, colB))[]
```

Comment: @jangorecki, any idea why I do get the warning messages? Should I post an issue on github?

Comment: I think it's posted here: [Overbroad issue about .. being defined in calling scope?](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2988). Cheers

Comment: @Henrik, Thanks. Looks pretty close, indeed.

Comment: I get an error while trying to use the env approach: 
>   dt[, (colC) := .SD[, x] * .SD[, y], env = I(list(x = colA, y = colB))][]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`((colC), .SD[, x] * .SD[, y]), env = I(list(x = colA,  : 
  unused argument (env = I(list(x = colA, y = colB)))

The link you posted shows to the news of the not published version of 1.14.9, and item 10 makes sense. But it does not seem to be published yet?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you were trying to do :

```
library(data.table)
dt[, (colC) := .SD[, colA, with = FALSE] * .SD[,colB, with = FALSE]]
```

Comment: this will get much simpler, and probably more efficient after https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Uwes great Answer:

I wondered which of the 3 options is the fastest, maybe someone might be interested as well.

Here is my script:

```
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(12)

library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

dt_size <- 1e8

colA <- paste0('a', 1:3)
colB <- paste0('b', 1:3)
colC <- paste0('c', 1:3)

dt <- 
  data.table(
    'a1' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'a2' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'a3' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b1' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b2' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T),
    'b3' = sample(1:1000, size = dt_size, replace = T)
  )

format(object.size(dt), units = 'auto')

option_prefix <- function(){
  
  dt[, (colC) := .SD[, ..colA] * .SD[, ..colB]]
  
}

option_mget <- function(){
  
  dt[, (colC) := .SD[, mget(colA)] * .SD[, mget(colB)]]
  
}

option_env <- function(){
  
  dt[, (colC) := .SD[, x] * .SD[, y], env = I(list(x = colA, y = colB))]
  
}

microbenchmark(option_prefix(), option_mget(), option_env(), times = 25, unit = 's')
```

I created a bigger data table with 1e8 rows, resulting in an object size of ~2.2 GB. The results are:

```
Unit: seconds
            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 option_prefix() 2.899609 3.651539 4.003576 3.947137 4.082440 7.525974    25
   option_mget() 4.412265 4.729769 5.163416 5.026099 5.480827 6.756750    25
    option_env() 2.870627 3.544040 3.885725 3.712213 4.156751 7.243021    25
```